# Make video responsive when browser resizing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

I have a main video on my website that shows a green background when resized. I believe the problem deals with the aspect ratio of the video but my question is that is it possible to have my video height responsive to where it fits the whole video container?

**Here is a screenshot of my video when resized**

[image]

As you can see I have unwanted margins on top and bottom that I want to remove when resizing. The background turns green because I have the background get to success in bootstrap

```
bg-success
```

And I've also tried setting the video to a responsive item and that did't work because it made the video take up the whole browser height and more.

```
embed-responsive-item
```

Here is my code and codepen
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LBREqe

HTML

```
<main class="d-flex w-100 h-100vh">
    <aside class="sidebar">
        <div class="col h-100vh d-flex flex-column justify-content-between">
            <div>
                <h1>Title</h1>
                <hr />
            </div>
            <footer>
                <p class="text-center">
                    <a href="index.html">Home</a>

                </p>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </aside>
    <section class="workspace bg-success flex-fill">
        <div class="video-container h-100vh d-flex flex-column">
                <video autoplay loop class="main-video" controls="controls">
                  <source id="source_video" src="" type="video/mp4">
                </video>

            <div class="video-showcase">
                <div class="row no-gutters">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                            <video autoplay loop class="embed-responsive-item" controls="controls" onclick="firstVideo()">
                              <source src="" type="video/mp4">
                            </video>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                            <video autoplay loop class="embed-responsive-item" controls="controls" onclick="secondVideo()">
                              <source src="" type="video/mp4">
                            </video>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                            <video autoplay loop class="embed-responsive-item" controls="controls" onclick="thirdVideo()">
                              <source src="" type="video/mp4">
                            </video>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <div align="center" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                            <video autoplay loop class="embed-responsive-item" controls="controls" onclick="fourthVideo()">
                              <source src="" type="video/mp4">
                            </video>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</main>
```

CSS

```
.h-100vh {
    height: 100vh;
}

.main-video {
    width: 100%;
    flex: 1 0 0;

}

.sidebar {
    flex: 0 0 300px;


}

@media (max-width: 575px) {

    .sidebar{

        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 90%;
        max-width: 300px;
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
    .main-video{

        flex: 0 0 56.25%;
    }
    }
```

Comment: The video container has 'h-100vh' class. If you remove it, the video containter "padding" was removed. Is this what you want or you have to fit all browser area (without side bar) with your videos?

Comment: when you remove the "h-100vh" it puts padding at the buttom which is worse. Here is a screenshot https://gyazo.com/6dd59eb5ffb1d6437c6161f4dac7af91

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand I thing. If we stretch your videos to fill all browser area (that depends on computer screen), we lost the video aspect ratio. Can you take a picture of what you would like to get? An y-scroll to see the four smaller video is a solution for you or do you want always see all five video without scrollbar?

Comment: From the screenshot i sent above, I just want the video to fit inside the container when resizing. Pretty much I want it to touch end to end and be responsive

Comment: this article may help: [Fluid Width Video](https://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php)

Comment: Thank you but I've tried that and it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by adding

```
object-fit: fill;
```

to my main video and also fixed a couple more errors that will come when adding the code above. Here is my code

HTML

```
<main class="d-flex w-100 h-100vh">
        <aside class="col-md-2 d-none d-md-block bg-light sidebar">
            <div class="col h-100vh d-flex flex-column justify-content-between">
                <div id="header-div">
                    <h1>Simple Text</h1>
                    <hr />
                    <p id="sidebar-text">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br> <br>


                    </p>
                </div>
                <footer>
                    <p class="text-center">
                        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                        <a id="lang_selected"><b>English</b></a>
                        <a href="es/irma.html">Español</a>
                    </p>
                </footer>
            </div>
        </aside>
        <section class="workspace bg-dark flex-fill">
            <div class="video-container h-100vh d-flex flex-column">
                <video autoplay loop class="main-video" controls="controls">
                    <source id="source_video" src="" type="video/mp4">
                </video>

                <div class="video-showcase">
                    <div class="row no-gutters">
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                                <video autoplay loop class="embed-responsive-item" controls="controls" onclick="firstVideo()">
                                    <source src="" type="video/mp4">
                                </video>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                                <video autoplay loop class="embed-responsive-item" controls="controls" onclick="secondVideo()">
                                    <source src="" type="video/mp4">
                                </video>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                                <video autoplay loop class="embed-responsive-item" controls="controls" onclick="thirdVideo()">
                                    <source src="" type="video/mp4">
                                </video>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <div align="center" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                                <video autoplay loop class="embed-responsive-item" controls="controls" onclick="fourthVideo()">
                                    <source src="" type="video/mp4">
                                </video>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </main>
```

CSS

```
html, body{

    overflow:hidden;
}
.h-100vh {
    height: 100vh;
}

.main-video {
    width: 100% !important;
    object-fit: fill;
    flex: 1 0 0;
}

.video-container {

    overflow:auto;
}

.sidebar {
    flex: 0 0 300px;
    overflow:auto;

}

#header-div{

    word-wrap:break-word;
}

@media (max-width: 575px) {

    .sidebar {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 90%;
        max-width: 300px;
        transform: translateX(-100%);

    }

    .main-video {
        flex: 0 0 56.25%;
    }
}
```